# Add extra column from SQL recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a problem with a recursive request. Before I explain: I use PostgreSQL 8.4.

I have, to sum it up, 2 tables: t_object and t_package
t_object has 3 columns: id, name and package_id
t_package has 3 columns: id, name and parent_id
(this is a very schematic representation. This is, in fact, Enterprise Architect's project database)

t_package.parent_id is the package's parent package, you guessed it.
When following the breadcrumb recursively, one can obtain an object top package. For example:

```
TOPPACKAGE
|
+--PACKAGE
   |
   +--ANOTHERPACKAGE
      |
      +--ANOBJECT
      +--ANOTHEROBJECT
```

The thing is: there can be more than one top package...
My aim is to create a view, based on t_object, with an extra colum containing each object's top package.

I successfully ceated a recursive request to get an object's top package:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parents(package_id, name, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT t_package.package_id, t_package.name, t_package.parent_id
    FROM t_package
    WHERE t_package.package_id = (
        SELECT package_id
        FROM t_object
        WHERE name = 'The name of an object'
    )
    UNION
    SELECT t_package.package_id, t_package.name, t_package.parent_id
    FROM t_package, parents
    WHERE parents.parent_id = t_package.package_id
) SELECT * FROM parents WHERE parent_id = 0
```

Then, I tried to create the view that's t_object plus the extra column...no success so far!

I have to admit that I am clearly touching my limits with SQL here, and I have no idea on how to achieve this :(

Example data:

```
t_object:
id;name;package_id
1;'First object';11
2;'Second object';11
3;'Third object';14
4;'Fourth object';12

t_package:
id;name;parent_id
10;'First package';13
11;'Second package';10
12;'Third package';14
13;'First root package';0
14;'Second root package';0
```

(parent_id=0 marks a root package)

So the hierarchy is:

```
First root package
|
+--First Package
   |
   +--Second package
      |
       +--First object
       +--Second object

Second root package
|
+--Third object
+--Third package
    |
    +--Fourth object
```

the result I want:

```
t_object_with_root_package:
id;name;package_id;root_package_id
1;'First object';11;13
2;'Second object';11;13
3;'Third object';14;14
4;'Fourth object';12;14
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sidequestion: are you sure you are using the (extremely) outdated version, 8.4? And not one of its variation (such as redshift, greenplum, etc.) which was originally based on it?

Comment: I'm absolutely certain of the version. It's a pure Postgresql 8.4. And yes, it's outdated ^^

Comment: Do this `parent_id = 0` mark the root entities? (I have to say, it's kind of odd.) Usually `parent_id = package_id` or `parent_id IS NULL` marks the root entities, because that way, you can create a self-referencing foreign key too.

Comment: I have no way to modify the database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on 8.4 as well:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte(id, name, package_id, root_package_id) AS (
    SELECT    o.id, o.name, p.id, p.id
    FROM      t_package p
    LEFT JOIN t_object o  ON o.package_id = p.id
    WHERE     p.parent_id = 0
  UNION
    SELECT    o.id, o.name, c.id, p.root_package_id
    FROM      rcte p
    JOIN      t_package c ON c.parent_id  = p.package_id
    LEFT JOIN t_object o  ON o.package_id = c.id
)
SELECT   *
FROM     rcte
WHERE    id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id
```

But right now I could only test it on 9.6:
http://rextester.com/QCZPS53546

*Note*: the main idea here is to select the root entities first. Then go through every path, until the leaves of the hierarchy. Also, collect every `t_object` in each step with `LEFT JOIN` (so the rCTE output will contain `NULL`s, where a `t_package` does not have any `t_object`).

Answer (score 0):

The word parents in your rcte is misleading, as it is really building up a list of descendants from the bottom up:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendent AS (
    SELECT t_package.* FROM t_package
    WHERE package_id in (select package_id from t_object)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t_package.* FROM t_package, descendent
    WHERE t_package.package_id = descendent.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM descendent
```

Really you want to start at the top and work down instead so you can carry the top parent id with you.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestry(top_id, package_id, name) AS (
    SELECT t_package.package_id as top_id
     , t_package.package_id
     , t_package.name
    FROM t_package where parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ancestry.top_id
     , t_package.package_id
     , t_package.name
    FROM t_package, ancestry
    WHERE t_package.parent_id = ancestry.package_id
) 
SELECT * 
FROM ancestry, t_object 
WHERE ancestry.package_id=t_object.package_id
```

By the way, using parent_id=0 and rather than NULL could get confusing.

To allow a referential integrity check against package_id to be implemented on this field, a t_package row with package_id=0 would have be inserted. This would then be the actual root of the tree instead of there being multiple root packages.